# How to Search File and give path to process builder

Tags: java

I am using process Builder to execute external command using java

Here is Code:

```
command.add(System.getenv("ProgramFiles") +"\\IrfanView\\"+"i_view32.exe ");
command.add("D:\\BMP\\*.bmp /import_pal=D:\\default.pal /convert=D:\\ABC\\*.bmp")
```

How can i Get Path if `i_view32.exe` is located on some other Drive or place (Don't know the exact location ).

Can we find the path and Run through Same process Builder.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class.getResource to locate a file on the current classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API of class `java.io.File`: `list()`, `listFiles()` and there filtered variants. This helps you to check whether the file presents in specific location. These methods also allow you to implement file search mechanism: you can traverse recursively the file system to locate file you need.

Instead of implementing this yourself you can use this example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

But be careful: simple recursive search may take a lot of time. Do you probably have other ways to locate the file? System variables or registry (because you are on windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that exists libraries that provide search capabilities, but in your case you can write simple recursive procedure to find your file. 
Here is some pseudocode:

```
look("root")

func look(path) 
   for every file in path.getFiles
     if (file = "i_view32.exe") return 0; 
   end
   for every directory in path.getDirectories
     look(directory)
   end
```